# How to pass an array by reference?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing

I'm trying to pass this array by reference but my code doesn't seem to be able to pick up the function.  Help?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void print( int (&array)[], int lower_bound, int upper_bound );
int main()
{
    // generate array
    const int SIZE = 20;
    int array[SIZE];
    for ( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i ++ ) array[i] = rand()%500;
    // end generate array

    print(array,0,19);

    return 0;
}

void print( int (&array)[], int lower_bound, int upper_bound )
{
    for ( int i = lower_bound; i <= upper_bound; i ++ ) cout << i << " : " << array[i] <<     endl;
}
```

Comment: `void print(int *array, int lower_bound, int upper_bound );`

Comment: @40two Arrays are most definitely not pointers.

Comment: @40two: Please read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) (most of it applies to C++ as well) before spreading that misconception. Arrays are not pointers.

Answer (score 0):

> How to pass an array by reference in CPP?

You almost got the  right syntax, but you need the array's size, which you could specify explicitly if you only need to support one size:

```
const int SIZE = 20;

void print( int (&array)[SIZE], int lower_bound, int upper_bound );
```

or use a function template to deduce it if you need functions for different sizes:

```
template <size_t N>
void print( int (&array)[N], int lower_bound, int upper_bound )
{
  // code here
}
```

Note that there are more idiomatic solutions in C++. One is to pass begin and one-past-the-end iterators (plain pointers will do) specifying the range. Others are to use `std::array` for fixed size arrays and `std::vector` for dynamically sized ones.